# Select All child node of a parent nod where attribute = value in a xml file

Tags: php, xml

I need help of bellow xml search. I cannot figure out how can i search all child node from a xml file searching by attribute.
Details are given bellow.

### Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<systemConfigs>
    <systemConfig cnfId="1">
        <moduleName>Module 1</moduleName>
        <channeles ch="1">
            <channelName>Channel 1 of Module 1</channelName>
            <channelType>myFunc 1</channelType>
            <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
            <eu>myFunc 1</eu>
            <custScale>myFunc 1</custScale>
            <rawMin>myFunc 1</rawMin>
            <rawMax>myFunc 1</rawMax>
        </channeles>
        <channeles ch="2">
            <channelName>Channel 2 of Module 1</channelName>
            <channelType>myFunc 2</channelType>
            <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
            <eu>myFunc 2</eu>
            <custScale>myFunc 2</custScale>
            <rawMin>myFunc 2</rawMin>
            <rawMax>myFunc 2</rawMax>
        </channeles>
    </systemConfig>
    <systemConfig cnfId="2">
        <moduleName>Module 2</moduleName>
    <channeles ch="3">
        <channelName>Channel 1 of Module 2</channelName>
            <channelType>myFunc 1</channelType>
            <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
            <eu>myFunc 1</eu>
            <custScale>myFunc 1</custScale>
            <rawMin>myFunc 1</rawMin>
            <rawMax>myFunc 1</rawMax>
        </channeles>
        <channeles ch="4">
            <channelName>Channel 2 of Module 2</channelName>
            <channelType>myFunc 2</channelType>
            <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
            <eu>myFunc 2</eu>
            <custScale>myFunc 2</custScale>
            <rawMin>myFunc 2</rawMin>
            <rawMax>myFunc 2</rawMax>
    </channeles>
    </systemConfig>
    <systemConfig cnfId="3">
        <moduleName>NI DAQmx Task</moduleName>
        <channeles ch="5">
            <channelName>my Voltage</channelName>
            <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
            <channelType>thermo</channelType>
            <eu>EF</eu>
            <custScale>custPol</custScale>
            <rawMin>1</rawMin>
            <rawMax>10</rawMax>
            </channeles>
    </systemConfig>
</systemConfigs>
```

Example:
 I need this all data searching from the above xml by the attribute ch=4
How can I do this?

```
<channeles ch="4">
    <channelName>Channel 2 of Module 2</channelName>
    <channelType>myFunc 2</channelType>
    <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
    <eu>myFunc 2</eu>
    <custScale>myFunc 2</custScale>
    <rawMin>myFunc 2</rawMin>
    <rawMax>myFunc 2</rawMax>
</channeles>
```

I really Stuck here, Please any one help me with example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that we have this question answered already on this site?

Answer (score -1):

There you go:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<systemConfigs>
    <systemConfig cnfId="1">
        <moduleName>Module 1</moduleName>
            <channeles ch="1">
                <channelName>Channel 1 of Module 1</channelName>
                <channelType>myFunc 1</channelType>
                <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
                <eu>myFunc 1</eu>
                <custScale>myFunc 1</custScale>
                <rawMin>myFunc 1</rawMin>
                <rawMax>myFunc 1</rawMax>
            </channeles>
            <channeles ch="2">
                <channelName>Channel 2 of Module 1</channelName>
                <channelType>myFunc 2</channelType>
                <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
                <eu>myFunc 2</eu>
                <custScale>myFunc 2</custScale>
                <rawMin>myFunc 2</rawMin>
                <rawMax>myFunc 2</rawMax>
            </channeles>
        </systemConfig>
    <systemConfig cnfId="2">
        <moduleName>Module 2</moduleName>
    <channeles ch="3">
        <channelName>Channel 1 of Module 2</channelName>
            <channelType>myFunc 1</channelType>
            <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
            <eu>myFunc 1</eu>
            <custScale>myFunc 1</custScale>
            <rawMin>myFunc 1</rawMin>
            <rawMax>myFunc 1</rawMax>
        </channeles>
        <channeles ch="4">
            <channelName>Channel 2 of Module 2</channelName>
            <channelType>myFunc 2</channelType>
            <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
            <eu>myFunc 2</eu>
            <custScale>myFunc 2</custScale>
            <rawMin>myFunc 2</rawMin>
            <rawMax>myFunc 2</rawMax>
    </channeles>
    </systemConfig>
    <systemConfig cnfId="3">
        <moduleName>NI DAQmx Task</moduleName>
        <channeles ch="5">
            <channelName>my Voltage</channelName>
            <channelFunc>conFig</channelFunc>
            <channelType>thermo</channelType>
            <eu>EF</eu>
            <custScale>custPol</custScale>
            <rawMin>1</rawMin>
            <rawMax>10</rawMax>
            </channeles>
    </systemConfig>
</systemConfigs>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();

 $doc->loadXML($xml);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
$list = $selector->query('//channeles[@ch="4"]');
$node = $list->item(0);

echo($doc->saveXML($node));
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate answers. Instead just CV or leave a link.

Comment: mmm - how is it a duplicate answer ? and how can i tell ?

Comment: A duplicate answer is one that has been given already (in your case: retrieve the node by doing an xpath query that checks for the attribute value). You can tell by searching the site. The topic asked here is relativly trivial, so you could assume that this has been asked and answered before. Therefore you search for the answer (which is easy for you because you already have a concept how you would answer it, e.g. you add xpath in your search). Then you find the answer, then you link it.

Comment: Thanks Adidi, It helps me, I need little more help. Please let me know how can I get all node values(after the search) in a array or variables Example:    foreach($node as $n) { $cName = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "channelName" ); }